# How to set specific work item permissions on Team Foundation Server 2010

Tags: permissions, tfs-workitem

In TFS2010 Areas and iterations, I can set users permissions to:

- **Edit work items in this node**
- **View work items in this node**

But I don't want to let one user change another user work item.

Is this possible somehow? If I remove the "edit work items" permission they can't change even their own work items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our team has taken a different approach.

Most of our TFS Team projects are open to all contributors. We allow almost anyone to update almost anything. The reasoning is that mistakes will be few and since TFS versions everything (Except Labels) we can always find out if someone is not playing nicely with others.

Think about why you are trying to control editing of work items. Do you really need such fine grained control?

Comment: I'm just trying to follow the principle of least privilege, and avoid unwanted surprises. They really don't have any need to change any other work items except their own. I want to leave the creation/editing to the architects, coordinators and managers eventually.

Comment: I understand your least privilege concerns. We had to balance our concern that someone would do something wrong with the fast that we have developers around the world and expect that someone should be able to help someone else without having to get access to something. We have a typical IT development team with varied skill sets. So far everyone is playing well together. Many here did not believe it would work out so well. Fortunately it seems to be working very well for us.

Comment: Yeah I guess there is no other way. Good thing we can track every change made.